# Add splash screen Activity with Navigation Drawer is not working

Tags: android, crash, splash-screen

I want  to add a splash screen Activity to A new Project that uses Navigation Drawer

**it crashes**

if I don't use `NavigationDrawer` it work well I  tried it before and it worked well but when I want to have a splash screen in a project that it contains `NavigationDrawer`

[image]

and I add a new Activity to my project (splash activity)and in

**My Manifest**

I change splash Activity to `LAUNCHER` 
I changed this

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

to this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and other Activity 
I changed to

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

**my Manifest is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="aa.cc.bb.bbb">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

**Splash Activity**

In splash activity I use Thread to go to another Activity like this
in `onCreate`

```
 thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();  // if we want not to go back to splash screen again by press back , we should finish it
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

Comment: please post the logs

Comment: no error logcat?

Comment: thank you by adding this my problem was salved         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `manifest.xml` use:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create another theme in your themes.xml which is located in the res=>values=>themes folder.

thems.xml

```
  <style name="Theme.YourProjectName.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and then in your Manifest update the

```
   <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.YourProjectName.NoActionBar"
          android:exported="false"/>
```